# PHP how to make URL as per opened category (Like Stackoverflow)

Tags: php, url

i want to make the url like Stackoverflow. when i open my profile or any topic the url becomes like: `http://stackoverflow.com/myprofile`

so i want when user open a category the url will be like `StackOverflow` and the books of the same category will open.

i have lot of categories in sql table like:
* Books
* Magazines
* Business
* Economy
* Health
* History
* Humor

how i can do that please help.

Comment: this is called url rewriting. This is done with a `.htaccess` file

Comment: can u please help me how to do that without .htaccess???

Comment: No I can't. Others won't either because there is not enough information (code) to go on

Comment: Have a read through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask do some googling, have a go at it and come back when you get stuck

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I  and my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519032/change-url-from-wiki-phpwiki-sun-to-wiki-sun

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to share some information about the URLS in question, however, here is an example from http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/. This is a rewrite rule that will go in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?topic=$1
```

So your URL is `index.php/topic=something`.

The `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` correlates to the `$1`. It is a **regex** expression for letters and numbers. It essentially means anything like ***topic/something*** will map to ***index.php?topic=something***.

In this case `$1` would be your category names/IDs.